# How to query this output in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
    (CustName varchar(20), Country varchar(20), RecordedTime datetime, CurrNo tinyint);

INSERT INTO Test
    (CustName, Country, RecordedTime, CurrNo)
VALUES
    ('Alex', 'Australia', '2018-06-01 08:00:00', 1),
    ('Alex', 'China', '2018-06-01 10:00:00', 2),
    ('Alex', 'India', '2018-06-01 10:05:00', 3),
    ('Alex', 'Japan', '2018-06-01 11:00:00', 4),
    ('John', 'Australia', '2018-06-01 08:00:00', 1),
    ('John', 'China', '2018-06-02 08:00:00', 2),
    ('Bob', 'Australia', '2018-06-02 09:00:00', 1),
    ('Bob', 'Brazil', '2018-06-03 09:50:00', 2),
    ('Bob', 'Africa', '2018-06-03 11:50:00', 3),
    ('Bob', 'India', '2018-06-03 11:55:00', 4),
    ('Tim', 'Brazil', '2018-06-10 00:00:00', 2),
    ('Tim', 'Cuba', '2018-06-11 00:00:00', 3),
    ('Tim', 'India', '2018-06-11 00:05:00', 4),
    ('Jerry', 'Cuba', '2018-06-12 00:00:00', 4),
    ('Jerry', 'Brazil', '2018-06-12 00:05:00', 5),
    ('Jerry', 'India', '2018-06-12 00:10:00', 7),
    ('Jerry', 'USA', '2018-06-12 00:15:00', 9)

    ('Maulik', 'Aus', '2018-06-12 00:00:00',3),
    ('Maulik', 'Eng', '2018-06-13 00:00:00',4),
    ('Maulik', 'USA', '2018-06-14 00:00:00',5),
    ('Maulik', 'Ind', '2018-06-14 00:00:00',6);
```

Table Result :

```
 CustName    Country    RecordedTime           CurrNo
 -----------------------------------------------------
  Alex        Australia  2018-Jun-01 08:00 AM    1
  Alex        China      2018-Jun-01 10:00 AM    2
  Alex        India      2018-Jun-01 10:05 AM    3
  Alex        Japan      2018-Jun-01 11:00 AM    4
  John        Australia  2018-Jun-01 08:00 AM    1
  John        China      2018-Jun-02 08:00 AM    2
  Bob         Australia  2018-Jun-02 09:00 AM    1
  Bob         Brazil     2018-Jun-03 09:50 AM    2
  Bob         Africa     2018-Jun-03 11:50 AM    3
  Bob         India      2018-Jun-03 11:55 AM    4
  Tim         Brazil     2018-Jun-10 12:00 AM    2
  Tim         Cuba       2018-Jun-11 12:00 AM    3
  Tim         India      2018-Jun-11 12:05 AM    4
  Jerry       Cuba       2018-Jun-12 12:00 AM    4
  Jerry       Brazil     2018-Jun-12 12:05 AM    5
  Jerry       India      2018-Jun-12 12:10 AM    7
  Jerry       USA        2018-Jun-12 12:15 AM    9
  Maulik      Aus        2018-Jun-12 00:00:AM    3
  Maulik      Eng        2018-Jun-13 00:00:AM    4
  Maulik      USA        2018-Jun-14 00:00:AM    5
  Maulik      Ind        2018-Jun-14 00:00:AM    6
```

I need the output which should cover all the below scenarios.

There is a thumb rule for how values should be present for "Audit" and "History" fields;

1. Records should have Audit = "ADD"or "CHANGE" & History = "NEW","BEFORE" or "CURRENT"  only for **Original Accts** (which means entries in table definitely starts from CurrNo = 1)
2. Records should NOT have Audit = "ADD" & History = "NEW" 
   for **Migrated Accts** (which means entries in table doesn't starts from CurrNo = 1, it may starts from 2 or 3 or any ascending numbers ) for this type of accounts the Audit should have "CHANGE" and History fields should have "BEFORE"or "CURRENT"

**Scenario1**:
If given input date as 2018-Jun-01 then the output should be as below (i.e. When a record is added and edited multiple times in a same day)

```
CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
   Alex        Australia  2018-Jun-01 08:00 AM   ADD      NEW
   Alex        Australia  2018-Jun-01 08:00 AM   CHANGE   BEFORE
   Alex        Japan      2018-Jun-01 11:00 AM   CHANGE   CURRENT
   John        Australia  2018-Jun-01 08:00 AM   ADD      NEW
```

**Scenario2**:
If given input date as 2018-Jun-02 then the output should be as below (i.e. When a record is already present in previous days and same record is edited today and any new record present today)

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
   John        Australia  2018-Jun-01 08:00 AM   CHANGE   BEFORE
   John        China      2018-Jun-02 08:00 AM   CHANGE   CURRENT
   Bob         Australia  2018-Jun-02 09:00 AM   ADD      NEW
```

**Scenario3**:
If given input date as 2018-Jun-03 then the output should be as below (i.e. When a recorded is edited multiple times the same day then it should list the last record for latest previous date and then the last record for current given date)

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
   Bob         Australia  2018-Jun-02 09:00 AM   CHANGE   BEFORE
   Bob         India      2018-Jun-03 12:55 AM   CHANGE   CURRENT
```

**Scenario4**:
If given input date as 2018-Jun-10 then output should be as below

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
   Tim         Brazil     2018-Jun-10 12:00 AM    CHANGE   CURRENT
```

**Scenario5**:
If given input date as 2018-Jun-11 then output should be as below (i.e. similar to Scenario 2)

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
   Tim         Brazil     2018-Jun-10 12:00 AM    CHANGE   BEFORE
   Tim         India      2018-Jun-11 12:05 AM    CHANGE   CURRENT
```

**Scenario6**:
If given input date as 2018-Jun-12 then output should be as below (i.e. similar to Scenario 3)

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Jerry       Cuba       2018-Jun-12 12:00 AM    CHANGE   BEFORE
    Jerry       USA        2018-Jun-12 12:15 AM    CHANGE   CURRENT
    Maulik      Aus        2018-Jun-12 00:00 AM    CHANGE   CURRENT
```

If given input date as 2018-Jun-13 then output should be as below

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Maulik      Aus        2018-Jun-12 00:00 AM    CHANGE   BEFORE
    Maulik      Eng        2018-Jun-13 00:00 AM    CHANGE   CURRENT
```

If given input date as 2018-Jun-14 then output should be as below

```
   CustName    Country    RecordedTime           Audit    History
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Maulik      Eng        2018-Jun-13 00:00 AM    CHANGE   BEFORE
    Maulik      Ind        2018-Jun-14 00:00 AM    CHANGE   CURRENT
```

And below is current code I'm using (Which satisfies Scenario 2 and 3, but not satisfies rest of them);

```
declare @d date='2018-Jun-03'

; with Indexer as 
(
    select 
        *, 
        rn= row_number() over(partition by CustName order by RecordedTime),
        rn2=row_number() over(partition by CustName order by RecordedTime desc)
    from records
)
,GetValidCustomerRecords as
(
    select 
        CustName,
        Country,
        RecordedTime,
        Audit   = case when cast(RecordedTime as date)=@d and rn=1 then 'add' else 'change' end,
        History = case 
                    when cast(RecordedTime as date)=@d and rn=1 
                    then 'new' 
                    when cast(RecordedTime as date)<@d and rn=1 
                    then 'before'
                    else 'current' end
    from Indexer i 
    where CustName in
    (
    select 
        distinct CustName 
    from records
    where cast(RecordedTime as date)=@d
    ) 
    and (rn=1 or rn2=1) and cast(RecordedTime as date)<=@d
)

select * from GetValidCustomerRecords
order by CustName, RecordedTime
```

Any SQL experts can modify this query to satisfy all the scenarios? Much appreciated and thanks.

Note: There is similar question in here just for reference - [How to retrieve data from SQL Server based on below example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039577/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sql-server-based-on-below-example)

Comment: For Scenario 1, why one record for Country "India" is not there?\

Comment: @maulikkansara its because no matter how many edits made on the same day, the result should show only the latest record. Also there will be no record for China too in same scenario because of the same reason.

Comment: You will encourage others to look at your issue if you provide a complete script that includes DDL and sample data - not just the query you are currently using.

Comment: This post has some pointers on posting DDL and DML. [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: in scenario 5, logic for first record?

Comment: @maulik In scenario 5 for Tim on given input date as 11 th june ;who is already present in previous date i. e. Jun 10 so that last record for tim on previous date should be displayed as "CHANGE" & "BEFORE", and on current date there are multiple records for Tim so it should display the latest record for Tim on current date with "CHANGE" & "CURRENT". And i corrected the date as june 10 for first entry for scenario 5

Comment: @SMor and Eric Brandit thanks for the tip, i have included the DDL and sample data in Tsql script

Comment: @Mar1009, please verify and make sure that output mentioned for each scenario is correct. This time i thing for scenario 4, recorded date should be 2018-Jun-10 instead of 2018-Jun-03.

Comment: @maulikkansara yes you are correct, it should be 2018-Jun-10 for scenario 4. And all other dates were verified. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Mar1009, i think still a correction required. In scenario 3, 12:55 AM is not valid. and there should be a record of 2018-06-03 09:50 instead of 2018-06-03 00:55.

Comment: Well, this is far too broad for Stackoverflow, however can't be closed due to the bounty....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

Please check if the below solution solves all your needs. I tested it with your data and with some more rows, but it is always best to re-check. In first glance it seems like it returns the requested result. I will add some explanation later on

The query I am using it this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-06-12';
with MyCTE as (
    SELECT 
        t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime,t.CurrNo, D = CONVERT(DATE, RecordedTime)
        ,RN_D = ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName order by t.CurrNo desc)
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName order by t.CurrNo)
        ,RN_Old = ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName, (CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, RecordedTime) < @Date then 0 else 1 END) order by t.CurrNo desc)
        ,Cnt = COUNT(*) 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName)
        ,CntToday = COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, RecordedTime) = @Date THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName)
    FROM Test t
    where 
        -- returns rows untill current date
        CONVERT (DATE, RecordedTime) <= @Date 
        -- only if relevnat to current date
        and EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM test t0 
            where CONVERT (DATE, RecordedTime) = @Date and t0.CustName = t.CustName
        )
)
,MyCTE2 as (
    select
        CustName, Country, RecordedTime, D, CurrNo, RN_D, RN, Cnt, t2.c, History, CntToday, RN_Old
    from MyCTE t1
    left JOIN (select * from (values(1, 'NEW'),(1, 'BEFORE')) t2(c, History) ) t2 
        on t1.CurrNo = t2.c
            and CntToday > 1
            and D = @Date
    where 
        RN_D = 1 
        or (RN = 1 and D = @Date) 
        or (RN_Old = 1 and D < @Date)
)
,MyCTE3 as (
    select CustName, Country, RecordedTime
        -- unmarke the bellow comment in order to get the accessories columns I used
        -- This is recommended to understand the line-of-thinking
        --, D, c, RN_D, RN, CurrNo, Cnt, CntToday, RN_Old
        , History = CASE
            WHEN CurrNo = 1 and Cnt = 1 then 'NEW'
            WHEN RN_D = 1 then 'CURRENT'
            else ISNULL(History,'BEFORE')
        END
    from MyCTE2
)
select CustName, Country, RecordedTime--, D, c, RN_D, RN, CurrNo, Cnt, CntToday, RN_Old
    ,Audit = CASE when History='New' then 'ADD' else 'CHANGE'  END
    , History
from MyCTE3
```

To make it simpler to test I insert the entire query into table function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.F
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F(@Date DATE)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (

--DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-06-12';
with MyCTE as (
    SELECT 
        t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime,t.CurrNo, D = CONVERT(DATE, RecordedTime)
        ,RN_D = ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName order by t.CurrNo desc)
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName order by t.CurrNo)
        ,RN_Old = ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName, (CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, RecordedTime) < @Date then 0 else 1 END) order by t.CurrNo desc)
        ,Cnt = COUNT(*) 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName)
        ,CntToday = COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, RecordedTime) = @Date THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
            OVER (partition by t.CustName)
    FROM Test t
    where 
        -- returns rows untill current date
        CONVERT (DATE, RecordedTime) <= @Date 
        -- only if relevnat to current date
        and EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM test t0 
            where CONVERT (DATE, RecordedTime) = @Date and t0.CustName = t.CustName
        )
)
,MyCTE2 as (
    select
        CustName, Country, RecordedTime, D, CurrNo, RN_D, RN, Cnt, t2.c, History, CntToday, RN_Old
    from MyCTE t1
    left JOIN (select * from (values(1, 'NEW'),(1, 'BEFORE')) t2(c, History) ) t2 
        on t1.CurrNo = t2.c
            and CntToday > 1
            and D = @Date
    where 
        RN_D = 1 
        or (RN = 1 and D = @Date) 
        or (RN_Old = 1 and D < @Date)
)
,MyCTE3 as (
    select CustName, Country, RecordedTime
        -- unmarke the bellow comment in order to get the accessories columns I used
        -- This is recommended to understand the line-of-thinking
        --, D, c, RN_D, RN, CurrNo, Cnt, CntToday, RN_Old
        , History = CASE
            WHEN CurrNo = 1 and Cnt = 1 then 'NEW'
            WHEN RN_D = 1 then 'CURRENT'
            else ISNULL(History,'BEFORE')
        END
    from MyCTE2
)
select CustName, Country, RecordedTime--, D, c, RN_D, RN, CurrNo, Cnt, CntToday, RN_Old
    ,Audit = CASE when History='New' then 'ADD' else 'CHANGE'  END
    , History
from MyCTE3
--order by CustName, RecordedTime
)
GO
```

Using the function it simpler to make multiple test, but probably in the production you will want to use the direct query

```
-- Test
select * from F('2018-06-01') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-02') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-03') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-10') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-11') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-12') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-13') order by CustName , RecordedTime
select * from F('2018-06-14') order by CustName , RecordedTime
```

/**************** Update at 2018-08-19 14:05 Israel Time ****************/

I notice that some more information is important to add for the sake of the participate in the thread. I hope this will be useful

> **NOTE!** tested on Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

First, let's compare percentage of resources uses according to the Execution Plans of three queries: (1) My solution, (2) maulik kansara seconds solution after update the first solution, and (3) maulik kansara first solution

[image]

Now lets check the image of the EP of maulik kansara seconds solution:

[image]

This query scans the table 11 times!

> ** **Important!** EP is not the only parameter that suggestes which query we should choose, but this is probably the first information we should check. In addition we should check IO statistics and Time statistics, and more...
>
> **Credit:** The image was taken using sentryone tool. There is a free version which can gives most of what DBAs need. I am using the full version which I got for free as Microsoft MVP, so Thanks ;-)

Comment: Special thanks @Ronen Ariely for your answer it works well too and loved the logic you came up with. I tested this in Production and works well too.

Comment: By the way, I have no idea why you selected my solution as answer but yet @maulik-kansara got the bonus points. I really hope for you that you do not use his solution. Using the DDL+DML in the thread, his new solution is not a lot better than the first one, according to the execution. In fact his second solution still scans the same table 12 times!! It seems like he thought that if you do not explicitly write "from TableName" then it will not scan the table and don't really understand how SQL Server works.

Comment: I will try to put a short explanation since this is important, but I cannot really do a lot in stackoverflow poor interface. I can only add short poor comments here ;-(

Comment: @maulikkansara I hope you see this message since this is critical basic information that any DBA must know: SQL Server does not execute your query as it is but he have a pre-step where a Query Engine parse the test and choose an Execution Plan (EP). It test several options and choose one. That EP by default is stored for future uses. Next time the server need to execute the same query he can skip the first step and use the EP that he already have.

Comment: Building all the EP and choose one (in first step) can cost a lot of resources and sometime even more than the execution itself, which is why using the EP next time works faster. The most basic tool that anyone who write quires is the EP, which tell us exactly how the server executed your query behind the scene.

Comment: If you will check the execution plan of the update query you will see that this query still scans the table 12 times (I add image in the answer as update).

Comment: With that being said my solution uses twice a task name "Table Spool" which we might remove and even improve the solution more. My solution is not the best that I could came with probably. The EP is depended on thousands of parameters and for the same query in two different tables, the server might build/choose a different EP, and since the OP did not gave us any relevant information to discuss performance like his DDL, DML, Version, real EP, and so on... I came up with the first basic solution that came to my mind an which fit the DDL+DML that was posted in the thread ;-)

Comment: here is the comparison of stats io and time between yours and maulk's code which I tested with production data - https://imgur.com/a/KpLwFYl

Comment: The link does not work for me. I am getting error "Zoinks! You've taken a wrong turn". Anyhow, this is not important since what is important is the result that you get in the real server. I can only advice to check and not what to use. If you checked all options and selected according to the real monitoring that go by this ;-)

Comment: Okay! excuse me for the picture error (I don't know how to insert pic in comment section, i'm new to this), I was about to display that your code uses much lesser  scan count and logical reads when compared to all the answers provided. So I take your advice and go with your solution. again thanks for the help.

Comment: I can see the link now... Awesome... fit the expected result ;-) You can see that my solution times is 93ms for the CPU and total of 312 ms while maulik kansara solution uses almost 2 second of CPU (1828 ms) and execute in total of more then 2 second! 2117ms... It is clear that this solution should be used in this case

Comment: As I said, I have no idea why @maulik-kansara got the bonus points while your selects confirms that my solution fit you much better (about 10 times faster) :-)

Comment: Initially I first applied his output before yours and even accepted his answer , after that only I tested all the other solutions and yours too, so all I could do is undo the maulik's answer and accept answer for your solution but couldn't do the bounty. Apologize I made this in a hurry (i should have tested all the answers before giving the bounty) if there is any way I could give you all of my points.

Comment: That is OK :-) I don't need the points. Thanks. I simply was wondering how this can be. I am not using stackoverflow a lot (I prefer MSDN forums where I serves as Moderator) and I read the rules that the bounty go the message that was chosen as answer. I saw that you chose my solution but he got the bounty which seems strange :-) Thanks for the offer. `Have a great day :-)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, Below is the logic for your required output

**step 1**

- get max(CurrNo) for given date for each custName.
- here it is cte.

**step 2**

- get first entered record for the mentioned date for All CustNames available in cte if any.
- in the union of above record, get last edited record for records edited less than the current date for All CustNames available in cte if any.
- here it is cte2.

**step 3**

- get records from #test table where currNo=maximun or currno=1 from this step, you will get last updated records and any newly added record if any for given date.
- here it is the first query after cte and cte2.

**step 4**

- get first added record for given date if any with Audit as change and History as Before.
- this is for custom special case requirement
- here it is the second query.

**step 5**

- get the first record from cte2 to get one records for previously edited record for given date.
- here it is the third query.

-

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
    (CustName varchar(20), Country varchar(20), RecordedTime datetime, CurrNo tinyint);


INSERT INTO #Test
    (CustName, Country, RecordedTime, CurrNo)
VALUES
    ('Alex', 'Australia', '2018-06-01 08:00:00', 1),
    ('Alex', 'China', '2018-06-01 10:00:00', 2),
    ('Alex', 'India', '2018-06-01 10:05:00', 3),
    ('Alex', 'Japan', '2018-06-01 11:00:00', 4),
    ('John', 'Australia', '2018-06-01 08:00:00', 1),
    ('John', 'China', '2018-06-02 08:00:00', 2),
    ('Bob', 'Australia', '2018-06-02 09:00:00', 1),
    ('Bob', 'Brazil', '2018-06-03 09:50:00', 2),
    ('Bob', 'Africa', '2018-06-03 11:50:00', 3),
    ('Bob', 'India', '2018-06-03 00:55:00', 4),
    ('Tim', 'Brazil', '2018-06-10 00:00:00', 2),
    ('Tim', 'Cuba', '2018-06-11 00:00:00', 3),
    ('Tim', 'India', '2018-06-11 00:05:00', 4),
    ('Jerry', 'Cuba', '2018-06-12 00:00:00', 4),
    ('Jerry', 'Brazil', '2018-06-12 00:05:00', 5),
    ('Jerry', 'India', '2018-06-12 00:10:00', 7),
    ('Jerry', 'USA', '2018-06-12 00:15:00', 9),
    ('Maulik', 'Aus', '2018-06-12 00:00:00',3),
    ('Maulik', 'Eng', '2018-06-13 00:00:00',4),
    ('Maulik', 'USA', '2018-06-14 00:00:00',5),
    ('Maulik', 'Ind', '2018-06-14 00:00:00',6);

select * from #Test

   declare @selectedDate date='2018-06-14';
with cte as
(
select CustName,max(CurrNo) maxno,count(1) cnt
from #Test where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 
group by CustName
),cte2 as (
select top 1 t.*,cnt
 from #Test t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)>0 and t.CurrNo!=c.maxno
order by t.RecordedTime  desc
union select top 1 t.*,cnt
 from #Test t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 and t.CurrNo!=c.maxno
order by t.RecordedTime 
)
select t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime,cnt
,case when t.CurrNo=1 then 'ADD' else 'CHANGE' End as Audit
,case when t.CurrNo=1 then 'NEW' when t.CurrNo=c.maxno then 'CURRENT' else 'BEFORE' end History
 from #Test t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 and (t.CurrNo=c.maxno or t.CurrNo=1)
union 
select top 1 t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime,cnt
,'CHANGE' Audit
,'BEFORE' History
 from #Test t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 and t.CurrNo=1 and c.cnt>1
union 
select top 1 t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime,cnt
,'CHANGE' Audit
,'BEFORE' History
 from cte2 t order by RecordedTime

drop table #Test
```

There is a nice point by "Ronen Ariely". And below is the updated query with 2 times table scan instead of 8.

```
with cte as
(
select CustName,max(CurrNo) maxno,count(1) cnt
from #Test where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 
group by CustName
),cte2 as (
select * from #Test where CustName in 
(
select distinct custname from cte
)
and datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)>=0
),cte3 as (
select top 1 t.*,cnt
 from cte2 t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)>0 and t.CurrNo!=c.maxno
order by t.RecordedTime  desc
union select top 1 t.*,cnt
 from cte2 t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 and t.CurrNo!=c.maxno
order by t.RecordedTime 
)
select t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime
,case when t.CurrNo=1 then 'ADD' else 'CHANGE' End as Audit
,case when t.CurrNo=1 then 'NEW' when t.CurrNo=c.maxno then 'CURRENT' else 'BEFORE' end History
 from cte2 t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 and (t.CurrNo=c.maxno or t.CurrNo=1)
union 
select top 1 t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime
,'CHANGE' Audit
,'BEFORE' History
 from cte2 t join cte c on c.CustName =t.CustName
where datediff(day,RecordedTime,@selectedDate)=0 and t.CurrNo=1 and c.cnt>1
union 
select top 1 t.CustName,t.Country,t.RecordedTime
,'CHANGE' Audit
,'BEFORE' History
 from cte3 t order by RecordedTime
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All the Scenario are passed except the Scenario1. There is a exception or special requirement for records added and edited in a same day, for example on Jun 1 "Alex " is added and edited thrice the same day so we need a same output for "CHANGE" & "BEFORE" for the values present in "ADD" & "NEW". To put in other words the "ADD" & "NEW" entry should have a other entry with same values but with "CHANGE" & "BEFORE". pelase see the result for scenario 1.

Comment: my last request satisfies, but 
when a record with three consecutive days of data added then it doesn't satisfies the scenario, say for example new custName = Maulik is added on June 12,13,14 (please see the newly appended sample data ).
when june 12 is the input it shows Maulik | Aus | 2018-06-12 |CHANGE | CURRENT - It is correct
when june 13 is the input it shows Maulik | Aus | 2018-06-12 |CHANGE | BEFORE & Maulik | Eng | 2018-06-13 |CHANGE | CURRENT- It is also correct

Comment: when june 14 is the input it shows Maulik | Aus | 2018-06-12 |CHANGE | BEFORE & Maulik | Ind | 2018-06-14 |CHANGE | CURRENT- here the CHANGE | BEFORE is not correct,
because when 14th june is given it should look for the latest previous record i.e. it should look for 2018-06-13 and that should be listed as Maulik | Eng | 2018-06-13 |CHANGE | BEFORE, but
currently the output shows the very first instance of that record for CHANGE | BEFORE

Comment: Can you please shed some light on this!

Comment: Ok will look into that also and will update you. one question. after adding new records, i think there should be change in result of scenario6 as well.

Comment: May I ask why?. Because it remains same as of now for "Jerry" and only "Maulik" should have CHANGE | CURRENT

Comment: for date 2018-06-12, now there are two custNames "Jerry" and "Maulik".

Comment: Yes indeed you are right, I just did not mentioned the obvious :)

Comment: Then please update. correct request required for others to help you properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178138/discussion-between-mar1009-and-maulik-kansara).

Comment: Good day, Before I start, let me say well done to Mar1009 on posting the question is such way that we can reproduce it and provide a fast solution. In addition I must say well don to @maulik-kansara for providing a solution. With that being said maulik-kansara solution scans the table 8 TIME! Which might be crazy regarding performance. I will try to provide a simpler query, but I always remind that performance is something that related to the real DD+DML and therefore in order to choose the best solution we must have real DDL+DML (including indexes for example) and the server exact version.

Comment: I do want to said in addition that moving to private discussion is not a good idea since you lose the rest of the people that might be able to help you.

Comment: @RonenAriely agree regarding multiple time scanning. But requirements changed multiple times with different scenarios. So my target is to freeze the requirement first with desired output.

Comment: It's weekend and I have time to help so let me first just check the MSDN forums  for open questions (one or two), and give me some time and I will post a solution which make more sense, assuming I understood the OP request `;-)` and I will not make mistake

Comment: Thanks @maulikkansara for your suggestions for last two days, I have tested this in production it works as excepted.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the different scenario's, they can be achieved by basically only 2 rules.

- Rule 1: The records for a CustName with the RecordedTime all on the same day.
- Rule 2: The records for a CustName with the RecordedTime over more than one day.

With a few window functions and an OR in the outer query, we can have two rules to target all scenarios.

And then use `CASE WHEN` to calculate the "Audit" and the "History".

```sql
 SELECT
  CustName, Country, 
  FORMAT(RecordedTime, 'yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm tt') as RecordedTime,
  (CASE CurrNo 
   WHEN 1 then 'ADD'
   ELSE 'CHANGE'
   END) as [Audit],
  (CASE  
   WHEN CurrNo = 1 then 'NEW'
   WHEN ReverseCurrRN = 1 then 'CURRENT'
   ELSE 'BEFORE'
   END) as [History]
   --, CurrNo, ReverseCurrRN, MinCurrNoPerCust, MaxCurrNoPerCustDate ,MinCurrNoPerCust, MinDatePerCust, MaxDatePerCust
 FROM
 (
    SELECT CustName, Country, RecordedTime, CurrNo
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustName ORDER BY CurrNo DESC) AS ReverseCurrRN
      ,MIN(CurrNo) OVER (PARTITION BY CustName) AS MinCurrNoPerCust
      ,MAX(CurrNo) OVER (PARTITION BY CustName, cast(RecordedTime AS DATE)) AS MaxCurrNoPerCustDate
      ,CAST(MIN(RecordedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY CustName) AS DATE) AS MinDatePerCust
      ,CAST(MAX(RecordedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY CustName) AS DATE) AS MaxDatePerCust
    FROM Test t
    WHERE CAST(RecordedTime AS DATE) between DATEADD(day,-1,@Date) and @Date
 ) q
 WHERE MaxDatePerCust = @Date
 AND (
    -- Scenario 1 & 2 & 4 & 6
       (MinDatePerCust = MaxDatePerCust AND (ReverseCurrRN = 1 OR CurrNo = MinCurrNoPerCust OR (MinCurrNoPerCust = 1 AND ReverseCurrRN = 2)))
    -- Scenario 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8
    OR (MinDatePerCust != MaxDatePerCust AND (ReverseCurrRN = 1 OR CurrNo = 1 OR CurrNo = MaxCurrNoPerCustDate))
 )
 ORDER BY MinDatePerCust, CustName, CurrNo;
```

You can test it on *db<>fiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=86924cf24c5a58e6841c9bf1b9880016)

Comment: Hi @LukStorms, check Scenario6. Using OP sample data your query returns 4 rows instead of 3 as the requested result. I did not read the query so I assume that this is probably something very tiny that need to be changed.

Comment: @RonenAriely Well spotted! Thanks. It was one of those times that when trying to fix one thing then another thing that was fine first then goes wrong because of that fix.  But it should be OK now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of if/and/buts going on in your original request, but maybe having an ALTERNATE VIEW of the data might be a better solution that you just did not think of or have been offered, so I will.

Why have individual lines showing both the before and after, why not do on a single returned line.  If there is no change, why show?  Maybe that is a later question.

To get my solution, I have a simple WITH from the test data that I am using as a baseline for my query.  You have your own CurrNo which may not always start with 1, and could even possibly skip a sequence number by some accident.  So my WITH declaration gets a sequential row number by customer and ordered by the CurrNo.  This will ALWAYS return per customer rows 1, 2, 3, 4 even if the CurrNo values may be 5, 8, 9, 11 (exaggerated starting number and accidental skipped values).  You could even change the order by to the RecordedTime to ensure logging based on the DATE per customer activity.

```
;with baseData as
(
   select 
         T.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustName ORDER BY CurrNo) AS CustOrder
      from
         Test T
)
```

So now, with the query.  I have my first table which is the basis for finding any "changes" within the system.  You will always start with these records.  Apply a date restrictive filter as you need.  The LEFT-JOIN will always be on the customer name PLUS whatever the row number is PLUS ONE joined to the NEXT of the same baseline data.  So, if just looking at customer Alex and Jerry from your data, you would have the following

```
Customer  Country    Time                  CurrNo   CustOrder
Alex      Australia  2018-06-01 08:00:00   1        1
Alex      China      2018-06-01 10:00:00   2        2
Alex      India      2018-06-01 10:05:00   3        3
Alex      Japan      2018-06-01 11:00:00   4        4

Jerry     Cuba       2018-06-12 00:00:00   4        1
Jerry     Brazil     2018-06-12 00:05:00   5        2
Jerry     India      2018-06-12 00:10:00   7        3
Jerry     USA        2018-06-12 00:15:00   9        4
```

So you can see the natural row number normalization between each.  So Now, my left-join is by customer AND the CustOrder column which will not skip gaps, so I will get records like

```
Customer  CustOrder   NextCustOrder        CurrNo      NextCurrNo
Alex      1           2                    1           1
Alex      2           3                    2           2
Alex      3           4                    3           3
Alex      4           (no 5th record)      4           4

Jerry     1           2                    4           5
Jerry     2           3                    5           7
Jerry     3           4                    7           9
Jerry     4           (no 5th record)      9           (no next record)
```

Finally, I am getting the data from the first record which will always exist and IF A CORRESPONDING NEXT record exists, it will show that new changed TO value.  That next record will be the next row and it's possible changed TO value and so on..

```
select 
        bd.CustName,
        case when bd.CurrNo = 1 then 'ADD' else 'CHANGE' end as Audit,
        bd.Country as CurrentValue,
        bd.RecordedTime,
        bdNext.Country as ChangedValue,
        bdNext.RecordedTime ChangedTime,
        bd.CurrNo,
        bd.CustOrder
    from 
        baseData bd
            LEFT JOIN baseData bdNext
                on bd.CustName = bdNext.CustName
                AND bd.CustOrder +1 = bdNext.CustOrder;


CustName  Audit    CurrentValue   RecordedTime              ChangedValue   ChangedTime               CurrNo   CustOrder
Alex      ADD      Australia      2018-06-01 08:00:00.000   China          2018-06-01 10:00:00.000   1        1
Alex      CHANGE   China          2018-06-01 10:00:00.000   India          2018-06-01 10:05:00.000   2        2
Alex      CHANGE   India          2018-06-01 10:05:00.000   Japan          2018-06-01 11:00:00.000   3        3
Alex      CHANGE   Japan          2018-06-01 11:00:00.000   NULL           NULL                      4        4

Jerry     CHANGE   Cuba           2018-06-12 00:00:00.000   Brazil         2018-06-12 00:05:00.000   4        1
Jerry     CHANGE   Brazil         2018-06-12 00:05:00.000   India          2018-06-12 00:10:00.000   5        2
Jerry     CHANGE   India          2018-06-12 00:10:00.000   USA            2018-06-12 00:15:00.000   7        3
Jerry     CHANGE   USA            2018-06-12 00:15:00.000   NULL           NULL                      9        4
```

If you don't want the "last value" for a record because no changes after, just change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN to guarantee something changed after.  But that would fail if you wanted to see all new "ADD" records without changes.  You could apply that as a where clause something like

```
where
      bd.CurrNo = 1
   OR bdNext.CustOrder IS NOT NULL
```

Additionally you could add a date filter such as

```
where
      bd.RecordedTime >= '2018-06-10'
  AND (    bd.CurrNo = 1
        OR bdNext.CustOrder IS NOT NULL )
```

As suggested in comment by Ronen Ariely, the above WHERE clause with the date would be applied to the WITH baseData as component, adding a

```
  where
     T.RecordedTime >= '2018-06-10'
```

to pre-filter the data before it gets to the rest of the join activity

Comment: Hi @DRapp, `(1)` this is not exactly answer but important information. Unfortunately this is exactly why I hate stackoverflow interface = we cannot make a discussion and post detailed explanation but only an "final answer" or poor comments. `(2)` If you want to choose your approach then you should not use JOIN but simply use the function LEAD. I am pretty sure that you will see a difference in performance. `ChangedValue = LEAD (bd.Country, 1) OVER (partition by bd.CustName order by bd.CurrNo ),` and `RecordedTime = LEAD (bd.RecordedTime, 1) OVER (partition by bd.CustName order by bd.CurrNo )`

Comment: `(3)` In addition you should filter the data as soon as you can which mean that on the first CTE probably you should use only the data that is relevant according to the input Date (the date the user is looking for relevant in formation). `(4)` I totally agree that the OP design/requirement is a bit problematic ;-)

Comment: @RonenAriely, 1-Some threads can go to chat window for more discussion. 2-Not familiar with the LEAD command but will read into it. 3-Agreed on placement of where, will adjust.  4. Yup, hence my alternative solution to their design requirement.  I think my approach is more direct and easy to read/follow.

Comment: @DRapp Many thanks for the logic provided, it helps a lot for me with other tasks too.